# How i can get appointments data by calling facebook graph api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api, appointment, facebook-messages, facebook-conversions-api

While i am calling

curl --location --globoff 'https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/t_1499689317517496?fields=messages%7Bid%2Cmessage%7D&access_token=<access_token>'
--header 'Cookie: fr=0Q7HE8QEHfxs7QGke..BlXIQQ._o.AAA.0.0.BlXJwZ.AWWjigSjQDs; sb=EIRcZUJfyziB2q-6hxBEcdJK'

this api then getting conversation messages. But for appointment data getting an empty string as show in the figure.

[api calling image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plzHw.png)      [Conversation image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jn1nD.png)

I have tried to called above mention api but did not get result as expected.